# Как отключить импорт функций из dll OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

Я пытаюсь подключить собранную библиотеку OpenCL в своём Makefile следующим образом:

```
target_link_libraries(warm_up1 ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/opencl/build/external/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/libOpenCL.a)
```

Но мне всё равно вылетает куча ошибок типа:

> libOpenCL.a(icd_windows_hkr.c.obj):icd_windows_hk.text+0x4 c): undefined reference to `_imp__CM_Open_DevNode_Key@24'

На другом форуме мне сказали, что это может быть из-за того, что импорт функций из DLL у библиотеки не отключен, и она всё ещё ищет их, но не может найти, т.к. .dll файла нет (и не будет, т.к. при сборке динамической библиотеки mingw ругаца).

Там мне посоветовали отыскать у библиотеки дефайн, который отключает это, но я, пролистав все исходники, ничего такого не нашёл. Что же мне делать?

Comment: `CM_Open_DevNode_Key` - это функция winapi, линкуйте недостающие библиотеки

Comment: Спасибо, это была библиотека Cfgmgr32.lib!